# The definite article usage in a sentence

Tags: definite-articles

Please have a look at the sentence below:
*This is the popular song of Taylor Swift.*

To me, if there isn't any specific song related to that singer known as "popular", the usage of *the* here is not correct.
*The* refers to the construct "popular song" here but more to the word "popular". And since apparently there isn't such a specific song known as "popular", we should use an indefinite article: *This is a popular song of Taylor Swift.*

Using the definite article can be optional in some cases but in this sentence, it's not.

Do you guys agree with me?

Comment: *Popular* isn't part of the name of a song; it's a description.  If there's one Swift song that's popular (judged by say, sales or downloads), then *the* is fine.  If Swift has no popular songs or more than one popular song, then the sentence doesn't make sense or it's ambiguous, but that's a semantic issue, not a grammatical one.

Comment: @deadrat>>"more than one popular song, then the sentence doesn't make sense or it's ambiguous", I agree with this.

Comment: This is the popular song by TS.  These are all the other songs by her; they were a disaster.  This is the popular dance move by TS.  I think she should do more dance moves...  I don't understand your question.

Comment: By "of" the sayer meant that, the song belongs to that singer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused.  To be grammatical, the sentence requires a determiner before *popular*.  Either type of article will do the trick, but they mean different things.  On the one hand, you say "we should use an indefinite article"; on the other you say the definite article is not optional.  The choice of article depends on the sense the writer wishes to convey, and that's not known ere.

Comment: Yes, it's not optional here. As I said, if there is such a song (known as popular), we can use a definite article, otherwise, we should use another determiner. Here, an indefinite article works well.

Comment: @franky : Were the sentence to mean Taylor Swift had a song named "Popular," grammatically, it would have to have quotes around the word *popular*, as in "Popular." Moreover, there would be no definite article used before "Popular." In order to mean what you suggest it means, the sentence would read, "This is the song "Popular" by Taylor Swift." It cannot mean what you suggest it does in its current format, not grammatically, not syntactically, not semantically.

Comment: @franky : As for the article, deadrat is exactly right. Using "the" in this sentence would mean that Taylor Swift only had one popular song. Again, it would not mean that the song playing was a song named "Popular." The use of "the" means this is *the* popular song by Taylor Swift, as if she has no other popular songs. As we know that Taylor Swift has many, many popular songs, the only article that makes a lick of sense is "a": "This is *a* popular song by Taylor Swift." By the way, even if one were intending to refer to Taylor Swift's current hit, it wouldn't be worded the way you have it.

Comment: I said "known as popular" not "named as popular".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you (in the absence of additional context) that the sentence should read,

> "This is a popular song by Taylor Swift."

However, if one asked, "What are you listening to on your headset?" the answer might be,

> "I'm listening to the popular song by Taylor Swift called, *'You Belong With Me.'*"

This example confirms your observations of where the definite article *could* be used appropriately (i. e., in reference to a specific song). However, even in this example, like you, I would still prefer to use the indefinite article:

> "I'm listening to a popular song by Taylor Swift called, *'You Belong With Me.'*"

Comment: I'll add that in the second example, it wouldn't be inappropriate to use an indefinite article, either.

Comment: I doubt about your second example. Is "You Belong With Me" the only popular song sung be her? If not, I'd use an indefinite article there again.

Comment: @BrianTung- I agree.

Comment: @franky- Thank you for your comment. You are right. I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is much to say on the definite article; it's a subtle subject. You are welcome.